# How to partition app's output into several files?

Tags: file, shell, file-io, zsh

So, I have an app. And it's not written by me. And it's a command line app. It outputs some strings which I am able to write to a file, like that:

```
anApp -input myFile.txt > myFileOutput.txt
```

The problem is that the output is way too large and the computer runs out of memory. Is it possible to do something like that:

```
anApp -input myFile.txt > i=0; for each 100000 lines; touch newFile%d $(i++); $cat 100000lines >> newFile%d $(i++); done
```

Because it is rather a clumsy pseudocode, I am also adding explanation:

1. For each 100000 lines (for instance)
2. Create a new file called: newFile# - where # is a number from 0 to n
3. Write those 100000 lines to a newly created file.

I think there may be also another option - to keep the output of the `anApp` in cash. However, the file's huge, it contains some results and if it will be lost... It's not something which I would like to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use `split`:

```
anApp -input myFile.txt | split -l 100000 - myFileOutput
```

This will generate files with names like `myFileOutputaa`, `myFileOutputab`, etc.

For more control over the names of the output files, you could use awk:

```
NR % 100000 == 1 { close(outfile); outfile = sprintf("myFileOutput%02d", i++) }
{ print > outfile }
```

You can save that script to a file and run it like:

```
anApp -input myFile.txt | awk -f script.awk
```

Comment: That's great! Thanks! Needed some time to test though, but as soon as I found it working, marked your answer as actually the Answer ;-)